# Affine state-space: Nonlinear output

Tags: dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems, asymptotics

I am using a system of equations to experiment:

$\begin{cases} x_1'=x_2 \\ x_2'=x_1^2-x_2+u \end{cases} $

As an output, I want to use the following non-linear output:

$y=e^{-x_1^2}$

```
AffineStateSpaceModel[{Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == Subscript[x, 2][t], 
  Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == 
   Subscript[x, 1][t]^2 - Subscript[x, 2][t] + u[t]}, {Subscript[x, 
    1][t], Subscript[x, 2][t]}, u[t], {Exp[-Subscript[x, 1][t]^2]}, t]
```

But the command [AffineStateSpaceModel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html) prevents me from doing this and gives an error:

```
AffineStateSpaceModel::sing: The descriptor matrix {{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}} is singular.

AffineStateSpaceModel::varslen: The variables specification {Subscript[x, 1][t],Subscript[x, 2][t]} is not of length 1.
```

**Question:** it seems to me that the error is either in the code, or you can use this option (introduce an additional variable that simulates the output):

```
    AffineStateSpaceModel[{Subscript[x, 1]'[t] == Subscript[x, 2][t], 
  Subscript[x, 2]'[t] == 
   Subscript[x, 1][t]^2 - Subscript[x, 2][t] + u[t], 
  Subscript[x, 3]'[t] == 
   Exp[-(Subscript[x, 1][t])^2]}, {Subscript[x, 1][t], 
  Subscript[x, 2][t], Subscript[x, 3][t]}, u[t], {Subscript[x, 3][t]},
  t]
```

*Am I right and can I use this approach with the [Asymptotic Output Tracking](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html) command?*

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 (Windows 10, 64bit) evaluates your code  without error. `Plot[OutputResponse["your state spacemodel", UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 3}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 
  3}]` works.

Comment: Same with version 12.1

Comment: Something strange...